# Creating new dataframe by selecting specific columns from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This seems to be a simple question, and it could still be, on how to create new dataframe by selecting specific columns from other dataframes.
Lets illustrate it by having a three dummy dataframes df1, df2, df3, where "position" is common column in all dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Position": ["A", "B", "C"], "Team1": ["xyz", "xyy", "xxy"],"Team2": ["xxz", "yyx", "yxy"],"Team3": ["xzy", "zzy", "zxz"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Position": ["A", "B", "C"],"T1": ["1", "2", "4"],"T2": ["3", "5", "2"],"T3":["2","1","4"] }, index=[0, 1, 2], )
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Position": ["A", "B", "C"],"T_1": ["IN", "IN", "OUT"],"T2": ["IN", "OUT", "OUT"],"T3":["OUT","IN","IN"] }, index=[0, 1, 2], )
```

I need to create, in this instance three dataframes where I merge Team1,T1 and T_1 on "Position"...now the catch is I do not know how many teams are there, df1,df2, df3 all will have same number of Teams, however number of teams can vary (in this instance i made it three, but in actual scenario it can be variable, say N), i want to know if some iteration can be performed to create dataframe based on the number of teams?

Here is the graphical way of looking at the Inputs (teams are defined for this example, but actually it is variable) and Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just concat horizontaly the relevant columns:

```
new_dfs = [pd.concat((df.set_index('Position').iloc[:,i] for df in (
    df1, df2, df3)), axis=1).reset_index() for i in range(3)]
```

It gives:

```
for i in new_dfs:
    print(i)

    
  Position Team1 T1  T_1
0        A   xyz  1   IN
1        B   xyy  2   IN
2        C   xxy  4  OUT
  Position Team2 T2   T2
0        A   xxz  3   IN
1        B   yyx  5  OUT
2        C   yxy  2  OUT
  Position Team3 T3   T3
0        A   xzy  2  OUT
1        B   zzy  1   IN
2        C   zxz  4   IN
```

Comment: looks good,..i was looking for something like this..however what is range(3)..can you explain that?

Comment: @ArunMenon: Oops... `range` is a standard builtin function in Python and the idiomatic way to build numbered or *ranged* loop. It builds an iterator from 0 (by default) up to n-1.

Comment: so should i edit range (3) to range (5) if i have five teams instead of three?

Comment: i figured out one way..i can use range(k) where k is defined as variable, and has value k=len(df1. columns)